# How to keep spaces in tags when converting xml to json in Java?

Tags: java, json, xml

I have the following xml:

```
<root><field>test  </field></root>
```

When I try to convert it to json,

```
    String xmlString = "<root><field>test  </field></root>";
    String jsonString = XML.toJSONObject(xmlString, false).toString();
    System.out.println(jsonString);
```

the result is like this:

```
{"root":{"field":"test"}}
```

How can I keep spaces in strings when converting?

Comment: Those spaces are unsignificant and would be removed by many tools. You can try adding the `xml:space="preserve"` attribute to the element, or enclosing the text inside a `<![CDATA[...]]>` section.

Comment: In my original task, I accept xml via http request and I need to convert it to json with saving spaces in fields. So I have to convert all fields to CDATA?

Comment: The XML library you're using may have a setting to preserve spaces even if the XML doesn't specify so. Otherwise if you have multiple fields for which you need to preserve spaces I believe you can set the `xml:space="preserve"` attribute on a shared root element and they'll inherit it. This needs to be done before parsing the XML, which is the step at which the spaces are lost (during normalization)

Comment: I use `org.json` library. When I set `xml:space="preserve"` attribute on `root` node (`<root xml:space="preserve"><field>test  </field></root>`), there are still no spaces in the string anyway: `{"root":{"xml:space":"preserve","field":"test"}}`

Comment: I've just checked the library's code, their XML parser is very basic and neither provides configuration to preserve whitespaces nor care about the `xml:space` attribute. It does preserve space inside CDATA nodes though, so that remains a possibility

Answer (score 1):

[Underscore-java](https://github.com/javadev/underscore-java) library can keep spaces while conversion from XML to JSON. I am the maintainer of the project.

```
import com.github.underscore.U;

public class MyClass {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        System.out.println(U.xmlToJson("<root><field>test  </field></root>"));
   }
}
```

Output:

```
{
  "root": {
    "field": "test  "
  },
  "#omit-xml-declaration": "yes"
}
```